# Parse & combine already rendered Json with "to-be-rendered" String with lift-json

Tags: json, scala, lift

Using lift-json I have a Field object which renders its own Json:

```
field.json => JsonAST.render(("id" -> id) ~ ("name" -> name))
```

Now I would like to combine the results with another Json String but doing this results in all Field-values being escaped as
the parser parses already-rendered Json:

```
JsonAST.render("combined" -> ("other-stuff" ~ getOtherStuff) ~ ("fields" -> field.json))
```

How can I merge those fields without one part being string-escaped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to keep those snippets in AST format and render only at the end.

```
val json: JValue  = ("id" -> id) ~ ("name" -> name)
val other: JValue = ("foo" -> foo) ~ ("bar" -> bar)

render("combined" -> ("other-stuff" -> other) ~ ("fields" -> json))
```